# How to show set of connectives is adequate

Tags: logic

I am reading over my notes and I can not understand how to show set of connectives are adequate. I understand that in order for a set to be adequate, **we must be able to express them in terms of the standard connectives**.

for example, we want to show { --> , #} is adequate defined by the truth table :

[image]

I want to express not p in terms of p#q but dont know where to start

here is the table given as the answer :

[image]

which shows not p = p --> (p#p). I am not sure how they got the p#p result on the table, if P is 0 from table 1 then p#q can be either 1 or 0 right? how is it that it is 0 on table 2 ?

Answer (score 2):

You have it the wrong way around. A set of connectives is adequate if you can express all truth tables using them. The standard connectives are adequate, so it suffices to show that all standard connectives can be written in terms of the connectives in the question.

As EuYu pointed out, I cannot use $0$, so instead we note that $p\#p$ is equivalent to false for all value assignments. Hence in the following, replace $0$ by $p\#p$.

We see that $\lnot p$ is equivalent to $p \to 0$.

We see that $p \lor q$ is equivalent to $(p \to 0) \to q$.

We see that $p \land q $ is equivalent to $ (p \to (q \to 0)) \to 0$.

Comment: I updated the question, can you please explain it a bit more? thank you

Comment: $\rightarrow$ itself is not adequate. We cannot allow the use of $0$, which is equivalent to adding a unary connective to our set of allowed connectives.

Comment: @EuYu: Why is a false value not allowed?

Comment: @copper.hat can you explain how p implies 0 is equal to not p? if you could give step by step solution to show not p in terms of the other two connective it would be even better - I must be over-thinking it :(

Comment: Well, as per @EuYu's comment I am using $0$ as a shorthand for $p\#p$, however for any truth assignment we see that $p\#p$ evaluates to false ($0$), so it is a reasonable shorthand. Look the truth table for $a \to b$ and consider the entries where $b=0$. Note that the value of $a \to 0$ is $\lnot a$. Alternatively, note that $a \to b$ is equivalent (from a truth table) to $\lnot a \lor b$, so if $b$ is false, this reduces to $\lnot a$.